# How can I access rowData outside of its function?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How can I access the rowData results outside of the function in the attached code snippet?

```
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(1, 5)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list('XYXYL'))
        self.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(35)
        self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)
        
    def _addRow(self):
        rowCount = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(rowCount)
        
    def _removeRow(self):
        if self.rowCount() > 0:
            self.removeRow(self.rowCount()-1)
        
        for j in range(columnCount):
            if not self.item(rowCount -2, j) is None:
                self.setItem(rowCount-1, j, QTableWidgetItem(self.item(rowCount-2, j).text()))
                
    
    def _readTableData(self):
        rowCount = self.rowCount()
        columnCount = self.columnCount()
        for row in range(rowCount):
            rowData = []
            for column in range(columnCount):
                widgetItem = self.item(row,column)
                if(widgetItem and widgetItem.text): 
                    #rowData = rowData +' - ' +widgetItem.text()
                    rowData.append(widgetItem.text())
                    
                else:
                    #rowData = rowData +' - ' + NULL
                    rowData.append('')
                    
            print(rowData)
```

Comment: @MwebazeIsaac what do you need that for? Can't you just call that function?

Comment: @manjari sorry, but proposing to use global is a *terrible* suggestion.

Comment: You need to return the data from the `_readTableData` method. Alternatively, you could turn the method into a generator and `yield` the individual values one by one.

Comment: If instead of rowData you use self.rowData, it will be data of the instance